# get button id on click with fontawesome icons returns undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, button, font-awesome

Issue when getting recently clicked button id. Form submit button decorated with fontawesome icons.

**Operation:**

1. On body `click` get button `id`
2. Submit form

**Concept:**

Mouse pointer over button click is working

> **Issue**:
>
> Mouse pointer exactly over button image(*example:round arrow icon*) click
>   not working.

Browser Console returning `undefined`

Any tweaks to make this work? Normally user will attracted by images and they will click over icons only. how fix this?

[JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jvsxo8s0/2/)

Comment: You could use [this](http://jsfiddle.net/q07b8ast/). But the question is, why are you binding the onclick event handler to the `body` instead to the element itself? Do you want to track clicks on other elements as well with this approach?

Comment: you can directly write `e.target.id`

Comment: @insertusernamehere what is the issue when using `body` as event handler? i have few `<li>` tags and `<button>`'s. i need to get `id` of recently clicked element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `body`, only set it to the `buttons` then.

```
$(function() {
    $('button').on('click', function(e) {
       var buttonClicked = $(this).attr('id');
       console.log(buttonClicked);
    });
});
```

**[Working example.](http://jsfiddle.net/jvsxo8s0/5/)**

I'm not sure if you want to do more work on the button click. So you could `submit` the form manually too in the callback. Just change the buttons to `type="button"` instead of `submit` and extend the callback:

```
$(function() {
    $('button').on('click', function(e) {
       var buttonClicked = $(this).attr('id');
       console.log(buttonClicked);

       // do your work

       //  submit the form manually
       $("form").submit();
    });
});
```

**[Working example.](http://jsfiddle.net/jvsxo8s0/7/)**

Comment: What's the point of changing the button types from submit if you're just going to submit them anyway in JS?

Comment: It is just an example, showing that you can do it anytime.

Answer (score 1):

If all you want is the ID of the button that was clicked, why attach the event to the body? I can maybe understand event delegation, but you only have two buttons here. Bind the click handler to both buttons. See http://jsfiddle.net/jvsxo8s0/4/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('button').on('click', function(e) {
    target = $(e.target);
    buttonclicked = target.attr('id');
    console.log(buttonclicked);
    e.preventDefault();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Dont know why you need the id, but you can use the `submit()` function from jQuery and `serialize` the form data.

```js
$(function() {
    $('#setpolicyform button').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        
        // get button id
        var buttonId =  $(this).attr('id');
        
        // form data
        var formData = $('#setpolicyform').serialize();
        console.log(formData);
        
        // check the clicked id
        if(buttonId === 'save') {
            console.log('save');
        } else {
            console.log('send');
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <form role="form" method="POST" action="#" name="setpolicyform" id="setpolicyform">
    <div class='box-body pad'>
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="lnbrd">
          <textarea class="textarea form-control" placeholder="Enter text ..." name="policyta" style="width: 510px; height: 200px;"></textarea>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="box-footer clearfix">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger pull-right" id="save"><i class="fa fa-save"></i>&nbsp;SAVE</button>
      <button class="btn btn-success" type="button" id="send"><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right fa-lg fa-fw"></i>Send</button>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: `serialize` not returning submit button details. my form has 2 buttons. so i must know which button is clicked to proceed further

Answer (score -1):

Use this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('body').on('click', function(e) {
    target = $(e.target);
    buttonclicked = target.closest("button").attr('id');
    console.log(buttonclicked);
  });
});
```

Updated Fiddle is here  http://jsfiddle.net/jvsxo8s0/6/

Comment: but yes the question is why you are attaching the click event on body?